# Is replaceable attribute obsolete in aurelia 1.0?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I was under the impression that `slot` superseded `replaceable`, but I've been told `replaceable` was reintroduced in the 1.0 release, is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replaceable` still exists due to a use-case that isn't covered by slots in the Shadow DOM v1 spec:

> The new Shadow DOM v1 spec has support for slot "fallback content". As a result, our `replaceable` attribute is no longer needed and has been removed in favor of slot fallbacks. However, slots do not solve the problem of replacing a template that is used by a `repeat`, `if` or other template controller. So, we still support placing the `part` attribute on a template controller's element and overriding it by using `replace-part` in the element's content.
>
> http://blog.durandal.io/2016/06/08/getting-prepared-for-aurelia-1-0-0-rc/

Comment: okay so to be abundantly clear; you don't need `replaceable` at all, but you can still use `part` and `replace-part`, correct?

Comment: no- you still need replaceable in repeats: *"However, slots do not solve the problem of replacing a template that is used by a `repeat`, `if` or other template controller..."*

Comment: Okay, thank you, what you had quoted was a little vague: "replaceable attribute is no longer needed... ...we still support placing the part attribute".